# Parsing array of objects using jackson spring

Tags: java, json, spring, parsing

I have the following request

```
{
  "name":"Ajeesh",
  "description":"hello",
  "platform_settings":[
      {"key":"value"},
      {"key1":"key2"}..  // This key value can be anything upto n times
  ]
}
```

I have created a POJO for the above as follows

```
package com.payunow.socialsharemodule.models;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;// in play 2.3
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Share {
    private String name;
    private String description;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return getName() + ", "+getDescription();
    }
}
```

How will I define platform_settings array of objects when converting the JSON to Java objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could declare platform_settings as a list of maps:

```
 public class Share {
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private List<Map<String, String>> platform_settings;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Probably should do `Map`, not `HashMap`. Let Jackson decide both `List` and `Map` implementation.

Comment: @Ajeesh Good. If it helped you, pls accept my answer.